# How to calculate exponential values properly in PHP

Tags: php, math, precision

Here is some sample code:

```
$principal = 30000;
$amount = 40000;
$time = 8;

$rate = $time*(pow($amount/$principal, 1/$time) - 1);

echo ($rate*100)."\n";
```

The output of above code is: 29.29 which is too high. The actual value should be 3.6615 approximately.

I have checked the formula multiple times. There is no mistake in the formula. So, why am I getting such an inaccurate value as answer?

Thanks.

Update: Try this calculator: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1232693402

with the values that I used above and you would get the correct expected answer.

The formula would be:

[image]

In my case, A = 40000 and P = 30000. Also, n = 1 and t = 8. What am I calculating incorrectly?

Comment: When I calculate it I get 29.29. Perhaps you can break down into small steps how you expect the calculation to go. Note that if you're calculation was instead `$rate = pow($amount/$principal, 1/$time) - 1;` you would get 3.6615

Comment: The answer you get is correct, given the math shown in the code. `8 * ((40000 / 30000) ^ (1 / 8) - 1) = 0.2929...`. (Where I'm using `^` to denote exponentiation, not an exclusive or.)

Comment: None of the online calculators show 0.2929 because that rate of interest is actually incorrect. I don't know what's going on. :)

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the math in the link you added.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk :) The formula for rate of interest seems to be what I used above. However, the fomula you are suggesting gives correct answer.

Comment: @ThomasJager they calculate `$amount/$principal` which I do as well. Then they subtract `1` and finally multiply by `$time` which I also do. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RealNoob You seem to be combining `n` and `n*k` into `$time`. You shouldn't be multiplying by `8` at the front, that should just be `1`, as `k`.

Comment: @ThomasJager Shit, I thought `k` was time looked at the formula multiple times. Did the derivation on paper but still misunderstood. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused between n and t.

The correct formula is

```
$rate = (pow($amount/$principal, 1/$time) - 1)
```

**t** is time, you have assumed **n** is time.